# I can fudge the cap! Read: Is this undownvote-after-rep-cap behavior by design?

Tags: discussion, bug, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I was at my rep cap (245), and downvoted someone.  I therefore had 244 rep.  Soon afterward, I got an upvote, putting me back to 245 (thanks to the new rep rules).  After that, I removed my downvote, and lo and behold, fellow unicorns: my rep for the day is now 246!

Update, FWIW: after a couple accepts (246 to 276), I downvoted again (276 to 275), and got two more upvotes.  This time, however, they didn't give me +1 like the other time.  I'm going to try undownvoting to see if it goes back up to 276.

Update 2: Yes, it does go back up to 276.  What's weird is that it doesn't either stay at 275 (like it should) or go up to 277 (to be consistent).  And my [rep profile page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10041/daniel?tab=reputation) still doesn't register the four downvotes/undownvotes.

Update 3: The +1 extra rep has moved to my latest upvote (which dates to *after* my last undownvote), rather than where it was on an upvote a couple hours ago, for no reason I can make out.  Stranger and stranger.  I just downvoted again, and went back to 275, waiting for another upvote.

Update 4: OK, no go.  The upvote didn't give me +1.  So maybe it was a one-time glitch?

Comment: Does your reputation audit page agree with this? Did you give the system enough time to do an automated rep recalc?

Comment: No, it doesn't, and I didn't.  I didn't know about auto rep recalcs.  How frequent are they?

Comment: A reputation audit should fix this. I'm not sure if the new reputation auto-correction system catches this behavior though. I didn't think you were allowed to gain back reputation you *spent* that day though.

Comment: It might take [5 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), if that's what @Oded is referring to.

Comment: It's been more like 15 minutes.  Also, the downvote/undownvote events aren't showing up in my rep profile page.  I thought they were supposed to.

Comment: @Daniel: Scroll all the way to the bottom and make sure the "show removed posts" box is checked. These might be included in that, I don't remember.

Comment: @animuson That doesn't work :(

Comment: Sounds like a good way to get suspended for _voting irregularities_.

Comment: It's been like this for as long as I can remember. It's a very common occurrence. Rep recalc solves the problem. I don't believe that the recent changes to the site have resolved this problem. Nick Craver commented as such here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes/124332#124332

Comment: So manual recalcs aren't quite obsolete?  My second question would be: why am I not seeing the downvote/undownvote events?